# Hot to add a row dynamically using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have two text box which is storing in database using AJAX. But I want to return back the new added row in table structure.

I am using this concept in add product to sell . when I want to add an item then it will be display in a tabular grid format.

This is my AJAX code.

```
    var xmlHttp
    function newVendorGridInital()
    {
    //alert("HI");
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    if (xmlHttp==null)
     {alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request"); return } 

    var  item= document.getElementById('itemcode').value;
    var url="ajax_NewVendorGrid.php"
    url=url+"?itm="+item; // For multiple value send.

    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random()

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=newVendorGrid
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null)
} 

function newVendorGrid() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 {
    document.getElementById("GridRuntimeData").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
           > > > I didn't understand how to target the id field > > > GridRuntimeData 
 } 
}
```

In my html page I have created a table structure i.e. head part.

In my PHP file I am returning the entire inserted row in a html row format using echo statement.

```
    <?php   
     echo "<tr><td>".$item."</td></tr>";
    ?>
```

and my doubt is how to show that row in table. If I write entire table structure in php code then it will be working fine. But i don't want do all the time to return entire row.

Please Help me.

Comment: What is the problem? You don't know where you want the row to go?

Comment: I didn't understand how to set an id inside table. so please clarify me how to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add rows to a table with Javascript like this:

```
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = 'new row';

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
```

[jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bCkjy/)